# Error when inserting in HashTable

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, segmentation-fault, hashtable

When trying to insert a string in a hashtable i am getting Segmentation fault error even when the postion calculated by the hash function is a valid one.

```
#define initial_size 23

typedef struct user{
    char nick[6];
    char name[26];
}user;

typedef struct hashtable{
    int size;
    user **buckets;
}hashtable;

int elements = 0;
int size = initial_size;

hashtable * create() {
    hashtable *htable = malloc(sizeof(htable));
    htable->size = initial_size;
    htable->buckets = calloc(initial_size, sizeof(htable->buckets));
    return htable;
}

int hash(char *string) {
    int hashVal = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < strlen(string);i++){
        hashVal += (int)string[i];
    }
    return hashVal;
}


void insert(hashtable *HashTable, char *name, char *nick){
    HashTable = resize_HashTable(HashTable);
    int hash_value = hash(nick);
    int new_position = hash_value % HashTable->size;
    if (new_position < 0) new_position += HashTable->size;
    int position = new_position;
    while (HashTable->buckets[position] != 0 && position != new_position - 1) {
        position++;
        position %= HashTable->size;
    }
    strcpy(HashTable->buckets[position]->name, name);
    strcpy(HashTable->buckets[position]->nick, nick);
    HashTable->size = HashTable->size++;
    elements++;
}
```

the error is in this lines:

```
strcpy(HashTable->buckets[position]->name, name);
strcpy(HashTable->buckets[position]->nick, nick);
```

When using this input:

```
int main(){
    hashtable *ht = create();
    insert(ht, "James Bond", "zero7");
    return 0;
}
```

I can´t understand why this is happening since in the case above the hash position calculated will be 20 and the hashtable will size of 23.

Any tips for solving the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be that you haven't allocated space for `name` and `nick`, only for the pointers to them.

Comment: Either that or your calloc to allocate the buckets is off.

Comment: @fredrik i have tried replacing the calloc with malloc before, but the error keeps happening, so i don´t think it´s comming from there. When you refer to allocating space for name and nick isn´t the strcpy used when inserting doing that already?

Comment: You are doing `malloc(sizeof(htable))`
This should be `malloc(sizeof(hashtable))`

Comment: Replace the complete line with
 `hashtable *htable = (hashtable*)malloc(sizeof(hashtable));
`

Comment: @AbhipsoGhosh i have tried that but the error persists

Comment: @MDordio `strcpy` expects both buffers to exist - it won't create the target for you. Your problem is definently one of memory allocation. Break everything down and make sure that it's done right. Read the man pages on expected input to the malloc/calloc functions and make sure that's what you actually give.

Comment: @fredrik so in the "create" method after initializing the buckets variable with calloc, should i iterate the new "array" and initialize each name and nick variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allocate memory for every bucket in your create() function.

```
hashtable * create() {
hashtable *htable = malloc(sizeof(htable));
htable->size = initial_size;
htable->buckets = calloc(initial_size, sizeof(htable->buckets));
int i;
for(i=0;i<initial_size;i++)
    htable->buckets[i] = (user*)malloc(sizeof(user));
return htable;
}
```